# Count Primnumbers in Vector

Tags: c++, vector, primes

How can I count how many prime numbers I have in a vector?

My vector `numbers_` contains 10 ints. 2 of them are prime numbers.

So counter should return 2 at the end of the function. But in this case counter returns 6.

Where am i stuck?

Thank you guys.

This is my code so far:

```
int numberClass::countPrims()
{
    int counter = 0;

    for(int i = 0; i<numbers_.size();i++)
    {
        bool prime = true;

        if(numbers_.at(i)%2 == 0)
        {
            prime = false;
        }
        if(prime)
        {
            counter++;                   
        }
    }
    return counter;
}
```

Comment: “Prime” doesn’t mean the same thing as “odd”. ([Prime number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_number) if you need to find out.) Write a function to check whether something’s prime, and then do the count using it.

Comment: Your function just counts odd numbers. For example, `9` is not a prime number, but `9 % 2` gives `1`, so `prime` will remain `true` and it will be counted.

Comment: I suggest starting with an `IsPrime( int number );` function first. Make that work and the rest will be easy. Even better: use `std::count_if`

Comment: @minitech no knowledge of elementary maths, tries to program. isn't that scary?

Comment: Use these numbers as a test case: 15 {3 * 5}, 21 {7*3}, 25 {5 * 5}.  The numbers are odd, but not prime.  Search the web for "Prime number sieve"

Answer (score 0):

It is obvious that the code that determinates whether a number is prime is invalid. I advice to write a separate function that determinates whether a given number is prime, to test it and to use it in your class.

As for your code

```
 for(int i = 0; i<numbers_.size();i++)
{
     bool prime = true;

    if(numbers_.at(i)%2 == 0)
    {
        prime = false;
    }
     if(prime)
     {
         counter++;                   
     }
}
```

then counter is increased each time when a number is not divisible by 2. However non-prime numbers also can be not divisible by 2.
In your code you simply count the number of odd values in the vector.

By the way 2 is a prime number.:)

Answer (score 0):

I followed your advices guys and implemented first a bool function to test if number is prime.

```
bool prime(int number) {
if (number < 2)
{
        return false;
}

for (int i = 2; i < (number / 2 + 1); i++)
{
    if (number%i == 0)
    {
        return false;
    }
}
return true;
}
```

now it works, thx.

Comment: use `for (int i = 2; i*i <= (number); i++)` instead `... n/2...`.